# What does the word "individual" mean in my code?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

In the code below the for loop prints out an entire list without brackets and in a straight line. However, I don't understand the word "individual" in it. Shouldn't the computer give me an error message because the word "individual" isn't defined or set to equal something? Furthermore, how does this for loop work to print out this list?

[image: the code I am talking about]

Comment: Could you please post your code as text? That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should educate yourself about the `for` loop in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`grade_book` is a `list` that contains more `list`s.

As the for loop progresses, the variable `individual` is set to the individual `list`s within `grade_book` (ie `kristen_grades, clarisse_grades, sapna_grades`).

Then when you look at the second for loop `x` is set to each index within the `list`s that is represented by the `individual` variable.   i.e `x` would then equal `90` on the first loop, then `85`, and so on until it finishes, then it moves to the next `list`.